# Excel: If the same value exist in column, take the first as ok and the second, third etc as worng

Tags: excel

at the moment i am facing an error in my excel. Maybe i have just brain lags, but i really don't know how i could handle it smart with a formular.

At the moment I want to have unique (E-Mail) values for each column. Every E-Mail should only appears once.

At the moment i use a "countif" to check if the email already exist.

At the Moment it looks like this:

```
firstname   lastname    1st attend      1st check   2nd attend             2nd check
Anton       Meyer   Ameyer@domain.com   DUPLICATE   Anton.Meyer@domain.com      OK
Anke        Meyer   Ameyer@domain.com   DUPLICATE   Anke.Meyer@domain.com       OK
Bernd       Meyer   Bmeyer@domain.com   OK      
Chris       Meyer   Cmeyer@domain.com   DUPLICATE   Chris.Meyer@domain.com      OK
Christoph   Meyer   Cmeyer@domain.com   DUPLICATE   Christoph.Meyer@domain.com  OK
```

Is there a formula that takes the first value and say it is "OK" and afterwards say if the same value appears "Duplicate"

Like this:

```
firstname   lastname    1st attend      1st check   2nd attend              2nd check
Anton       Meyer   Ameyer@domain.com   OK      
Anke        Meyer   Ameyer@domain.com   DUPLICATE   Anke.Meyer@domain.com       OK
Bernd       Meyer   Bmeyer@domain.com   OK      
Chris       Meyer   Cmeyer@domain.com   OK      
Christoph   Meyer   Cmeyer@domain.com   DUPLICATE   Christoph.Meyer@domain.com  OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNTIF is exactly what you want:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)=1,"OK","DUPLICATE")
```

Notice that the Ending Cell in the reference range is relative.  So as it is copied/dragged down it grows.  Thus the first encounter will equal 1 because it is the only one on the smaller range.

[image]

Comment: I had such a brainlag... i forgot to $ it. and put just the range till the cell is... thanks so much !